# OpenGL: How to minimize drawing?

Tags: opengl, glut

My OpenGL screen consists of 2 triangles and 1 texture, nothing else. I'd like to update the screen as little as possible, to save power and limit CPU/GPU usage. Unfortunately, when my draw_scene routine returns early without drawing anything, the OpenGL screen goes black-- even if I never call glutSwapBuffers. My background color is not black by the way. It seems that if I do not draw, the OpenGL window loses its contents. How can I minimize the amount of drawing that is done?

Comment: Provide a minimal code example which reproduces the problem, please.

Answer (score 1):

Modern graphics systems assume, that when a redraw is initiated, that the whole contents are redrawn. Furthermore, if you get a redraw event from the graphics system, then that's usually because the contents of the window have become undefined and need to be recreated, so you *must* redraw in that situation.

To save power you have to disable the idle loop (or just pass over everything that does and immediately yield back to the OS scheduler) and don't have timers create events.

Comment: Hi, sounds about right. About the idle loop, do you just mean the GLUT idle callback? I call glutMainLoop and I set the idle callback, but I don't do anything in the idle callback.

Comment: @popoe: If you use GLUT then yes, I mean the idle callback. You can turn off the idle callback at any time by passing a null pointer to `glutIdleFunc`. Or you can just yield to the OS in the idle function. Call `sched_yield` on POSIX systems, on Windows the equivalent function is `SwitchToThread`.

Comment: Wouldn't the idle function also be a good place to insert a call to usleep to ensure that the FPS is not too high? I'm currently seeing over 200 frames per second when there's no idle function and no update it needed to the texture.

Comment: @popoe: The idle function is called only when no events are outstanding. If you got constant redraws you're calling `glutPostRedisplay` unconditionally either at the end of each redraw, or inside the idle function. Sleeping can be used to implement framerate limitation, but the better way is to use a high resolution timer to throttle redisplays (i.e. don't call `glutPostRedisplay` if not enough time has passed since the last redraw).